# При запросе ajax и попытке перейти по ссылке браузер виснет

Tags: ajax, javascript, long-poll

Приветствую всех.

Я уже задавал вопрос здесь по long-polling, но сейчас меня интересует немного другое, больше суток бился, но так и не понял, как избежать проблемы.

Вкратце:
Я реализовал на стороне сервера цикл, который работает не более 30 секунд вне зависимости, имеются новые данные или нет. Так вот, AJAX ожидает ответа от сервера, и если в течение этого ожидания (30 секунд в моем случае) ответ не приходит и попытаться перейти по какой-нибудь ссылке, то браузер переходит в зависшее состояние и, пока не получит ответ, не выполняет указанное ему действие.
Можно, конечно, навешать на все ссылки событие по клику, на которое сработает `abort()`, но, мне кажется, это извращенно как-то. Если откровенно, я не до конца понимаю, как работает long-polling, и думаю, в этом моя проблема.

Ребят, какие у вас соображения?

Comment: У вашего открытого соединения должен быть выставлен timeout, который вызовет `abort()` автоматически, по прошествии 30 секунд. Как только Вы отловили `timeout`, Вам следует открыть новое соединение.

Answer (score 1):

Я правильно понял, что у вас на каждой из вкладок создаётся long polling соединение с сайтом? Если так, то всё правильно. Насколько я помню, по стандарту c одним доменом должно быть не более 2 соединений, chrome ограничивается шестью. Дальше он ждёт, пока завершится одно из открытых соединений.

Варианта два:

1. Неправильно:
   Отправлять long polling на разные подменены, обходя ограничение открытых соединений, но это неправильно, так как тот же chrom в сумме на все домены открывает только 255 соединений, и проблема повторится.
2. Правильно:
   Открывать на все вкладки одно общее соединение и все данные гонять только через него. А обмен сообщениями между вкладками проводить через событие onStorage.

Можете в качестве примера разобрать [JS API](https://github.com/Levhav/CometServerApi.js) от моего [comet сервера](http://comet-server.ru) (https://github.com/Levhav/CometServerApi.js).

Comment: я бы возразил насчёт первого варианта. И думаю он вполне приемлем. Врятли кто-либо будет открывать 255 вкладок в своём браузере, создавая тем самым 255 соединений.